# Rails 3.1 Thumbnail Image Rotation / Resizing On-the-fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to find out if there is an (easy) way to pre-process images in rails before they get served up through the asset pipeline. Notably i'm looking to rotate and resize the images, hopefully with something like

```
/thumbs/my_thumb.png?deg=35&height=50
```

Is paperclip something that would be able to do this? Presumably i would need to create a new model/controller and some kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if u want the image to be resized and saved, use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

and in ur view,

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```